# Deleting a file with name created using a string variable

Tags: c++, string, file

I am writing a function which will give users an opportunity to change their username. To do this I was trying to rename the file in which their data is stored. I have come up with a way of doing this, which doesn't quite work but I think I am close.

The filename is originally created like this -

```
std::cout << "Please enter a username: ";
std::getline (std::cin, username);

std::ofstream fout (username + ".txt");
```

which works fine. And then if they later choose to change their username

```
std::cout << "Please type in your new username." << std::endl;
std::getline (std::cin, newUsername);

std::ofstream fout (newUsername + ".txt");
// I copied the contents of username.txt to newUsername.txt here
```

which again works fine.

The problem lies below.

the problem lies in deleting the original file, more specifically when adding the file extension .txt

I have included #include  for the remove() functionality
And added .c_str() to username as I believe remover () will only take a C string (char*), not a C++ string.

```
remove(username.c_str() + ".txt"); // error expression must have integral or enum type         referring to ".txt".
```

Thanks in advance for everyones time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple enough

```
remove((username + ".txt").c_str());
```

The return value from `username + ".txt"` is called a *temporary* (because it is an unnamed value) but there is nothing that says you can't call a method (like `c_str`) on a temporary object.

Comment: that removes the error thanks, so now the program compiles, but for some reason it still doesn't delete the file username.txt? Can you think of any reason why it might not, or any extra code that might be useful I could post.

Comment: There's lots of reasons why this might be. We're talking about how your program interacts with the operating system, so it's hard to give definite advice. Some possible reasons, the file is still open (did you forget to close it?), you don't have permissions to delete it, the program is looking for the file in a different directory that what you expect, the program does delete it but then your program recreates it. Many other reasons are possible.

Comment: Remove returns 0 on success, so the first thing should be to check the return value of `remove`.

Comment: I should add one obvious possibility, the variable `username` doesn't have the value you think it does, that's probably the most likely.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to close the file. Been stuck on that for hours, Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

`remove` takes a `const char*` as an argument, and you cannot add two `const char*`s together using the `+` operator. Therefore, the solution is to add them as strings then call `c_str()` on the result.

```
remove((username + std::string(".txt")).c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
remove(username.c_str() + ".txt"); // error expression must have integral or enum type         referring to ".txt".
```

Adding two `char*`s doesn't produce a `string`.

This may be a better approach:

```
auto filename = username + ".txt"
remove(filename.c_str())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
remove(username.c_str() + ".txt"); // error expression must have integral or enum type         referring to ".txt".
```

Adding two [`const char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)s doesn't produce a [`(std::)string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

This may be a better approach:

```
auto filename = username + ".txt"
remove(filename.c_str())
```

Note that this produces a *relative* filename whereas an absolute filename may be preferable depending on how this is called.